# Android unlimited textviews between two fixed ones

Tags: java, android, autocomplete, textview

I have a relative layout with 2 autocomplete textviews.One is for a departure place,one for arrival. I need to set POIs afterwards between these 2 base points. User can input unlimited POIs and I want them to show out after selected inside departure and arrival. How can I achieve that? This is my layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="@string/offerTravelFragment"
    android:id="@+id/offerTravelLabel"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<AutoCompleteTextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/departureAutoComplete"
    android:hint="@string/departure"
    android:layout_below="@+id/offerTravelLabel"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="37dp"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/offerTravelLabel"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/offerTravelLabel" />

<AutoCompleteTextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/arrivalAutoComplete"
    android:hint="@string/arrival"
    android:layout_below="@+id/departureAutoComplete"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/offerTravelLabel"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/offerTravelLabel" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Thank you.

Comment: A custom `ListAdapter` could be used for this task.

Comment: So I should put my autocompletes in a listview and implement adapter to have those 2 autocompletes ,and afterwards add between them what user input ?

Comment: Or just use [`HeaderViewListAdapter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HeaderViewListAdapter.html) with a simple `ListAdapter` for the POIs.